# Prolog "recursive" query

Tags: prolog

I've started learning Prolog recently and came across a problem.

Some people sit around a table. We are given the fact `sits_right_of(X, Y)` (X sits right of Y). Then I wrote the next rules:

- `sits_left_of(X, Y) :- sits_right_of(Y, X)` (X sits left of Y);
- `are_neighbors_of(X, Y, Z) :- sits_left_of(X, Z)` (X sits left to Z and Y sits right to Z);
- `next_to_each_other(X, Y) :- are_neighbors_of(_, X, Y); are_neighbors_of(X, _, Y)` (X sits next to Y).

How can I find out who is the person who sits two places right (or left) to a given person? Is there some kind of recursive query like `sits_right_of(sits_right_of(X, alex))`? Do I need to write another rule for finding out who sits `n` places away from somebody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obtain values from a procedure the same way you enter them. Introduce a new variable and try to satisfy `sits_right_of(Y, alex)`. Then, this must also be satisfied: `sits_right_of(X, Y)`. The procedure can be defined like this:

```
sits_two_places_right_of(X, Y) :- sits_right_of(X, Z), sits_right_of(Z, Y).
```

Yes, such a procedure can be created analogically to this for every number or persons, or using arithmetics, if you want to make it a parameter.